# Get max value from a map with keys corresponding to a list in Java 7

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

I have a `Map<String, Double>` and a `List<String>`.

The list actually contains possible keys for the map.
Now, I want the max value in the map corresponding to the list of keys.

***For eg***:

Map

> (a, 3), 
>   (b, 4), 
>   (c, 5), 
>   (d, 6),
>   (e, 7)

List

> b, 
>   d

Output should be = 6

Current solution:

```
public Double getMaxValue(final List<String> list, final Map<String,Double> map) {
    Double maxDiscount = 0d;

    for (String key : list) {
        Double discount = map.get(key);
        if (discount > maxDiscount) {
            maxDiscount = discount;
        }
    }
    return maxDiscount;
}
```

How can I do it more efficiently?

Comment: @QualtarDemix: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This doesn't seem very hard, especially with streams.

Comment: I am using Java 7.

Comment: how about you first remove all elements from the map of which the key cannot be found in the list?

Comment: @WilliMentzel This is really bad advice. A method asking for a max value shouldn't alter its arguments.

Comment: @QualtarDemix iterate on the list. Find the value for each key in the list. If greater than current max, change current max. Done.

Comment: @JBNizet: Not if you use a temp map for it ;)

Comment: Or try to take one of many [findMax algortihm](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/java-finding-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-an-array/) in the internet. Only try to find a solution how you only use the elements you want to compare with each other

Comment: Still, it would be very inefficient to make a whole copy of the map, then remove everything from it, just to find a max. Read nits.kk's answer.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, you are right.

Comment: @Qualtar Demix  what result/outcome do you get from your current solution?

Comment: @JBNizet I was thinking why I came to this silly idea... I actually thought about it in Kotlin using higher-order functions like this: map.filter{ it.key in list}.map{ it.value}.max() and then I tried to convert it to Java 7 :D. How would you have done it in Kotlin?

Comment: @WilliMentzel `val max = list.map { map[it] }.filterNotNull().max()`

Comment: @JBNizet : what's list.map ?

Comment: @JBNizet truly beautiful, thank you :)

Comment: @QualtarDemix this answers Willi's question, about how doing it in Kotlin. That's not Java code.

Comment: @QualtarDemix actually your question should be: "how to do it more efficiently?" because you already have a working solution.

Comment: @Willi Mentzel ahh I have just spent ten minutes trying to work out why the current solution didn't work. That' why I asked what the current resukt was. Thanks saves me another ten minutes and puts my mind at rest.

Comment: @BusinessPlanQuickBuilder : I am really sorry for that. (no pun intended)

Comment: @Qualtar Demix no worries, I learnt  from  the surrounding chat :-)

Comment: @JBNizet interestlingly enough, if you would implement it in Kotlin, like in Java 7 (one loop) it would actually run faster. Because in the Kotlin solution you (and I) gave several loops are necessary. Question is: Do higher order functions / streams make us inefficient not when it comes to reading the code but the actual performance?

Comment: @WilliMentzel Streams are lazy, and don't need several passes for this usecase. We could use a Sequence in Kotlin, too. But unless the list is very large, I doubt it make any significant difference.

Answer (score 3):

Though there are other solutions (Stream API based) but I will tell you the basic algorithm to solve this.

1. Initilize:  `max = Double.MIN_VALUE;`
2. Iterate over the list: `for (String key : List)`
3. For each key check: `if(Map.contains(key))`
4. If `(max < Map.get(key))` is true then assign `max = Map.get(key)`

At the end of the iteration, the value of `max` is the maximum value you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I came up with. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Code being Elegant can be measured by its performance, amount of resource required, ease of maintainace, ease of scaling it... Thease are just few of the attributes of a code. Which one you are looking at, each requiremwnt has some non functional attributes. It is not mandatory for a code to have the exhaustive list of these quality non functional attributes, each of these does have some trade offs..

Answer (score -2):

Simple approach:

```
    Double max = 0.; //Or your min value (-Double.MAX_VALUE if negatives are allowed)
    for(String key : keyList) {
        if(hashmap.contains(key) && hashmap.get(key) > max)
            max = hashmap.get(key);
    }
    System.out.println(max);
```

You can use streams, but I don't think it's really a better solution (terribly difficult to read, and you'd have to use Java 8):

```
System.out.print(
               hashmap.entrySet().stream()
                  .filter(entry -> keyList.contains(entry.getKey()))
                  .max((p1, p2) -> Double.compare( p1.getValue(), p2.getValue()))
                  .get()
                  .getValue()
       );
```

Comment: Yeah. That's what I came up with. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Not that wouldn't be doing essentially the same thing under the hood. You could use a stream and a lambda or something like that if you just wanted it on a single line. But, I don't know that's it's worth hassling with to save 3 lines of code.

Comment: If Values contained are negative then this will not work, moreover OP question has a list and maximum corresponds to the maximum value for the keys contained in the list which may not be the max value contained in the map.

Comment: hmm But still there is no List, this algo finds the maximum value contained by the map. OP has mentioned he needs maximum value corresponding to the keys contained in the list.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't usually get to be terribly meticulous in my answers

Comment: Edited to add streaming solution

Comment: @Araymer OP stated that he is using Java 7 :(

Comment: That's why I noted he'd have to use Java 8

Comment: @Araymer why don't you add a Kotlin and C# solution as well and state that you would have to use those?

Comment: I'd rather add a bunch of snark and passive aggressive crap to a coding site *eyeroll*

Answer (score -2):

This should do it:

```
public Double getMaxValue(final List<String> list, final Map<String,Double> map) {
    return Collections.max(
            map.entrySet().stream().filter(
                    item -> list.contains(item.getKey())
            ).collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    e -> e.getKey(),
                    e -> e.getValue())
            ).values()
    );
}
```

Comment: OP said he wants to use Java 7

Comment: Ooops didn't saw it. But the current solution of OP looks great.